# getting selectedvalue from CheckBoxList DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the control:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListdepts" AutoPostBack="true" BorderWidth="1PX" BorderColor="#3f3a71" Width="100%" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcedepts"
                         DataTextField="dept_name" 
                        DataValueField="dept_id"
                         OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxListdepts_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

i have an array of 5 CheckBoxList and this is my code

```
protected void CheckBoxListdepts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBoxList[] mylists = { CheckBoxList1, CheckBoxList2, CheckBoxList3, CheckBoxList4, CheckBoxList5 };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                mylists[i].DataSource = (from ListItem rr in CheckBoxListdepts.Items
                                         where rr.Selected == true
                                         select rr);    


 mylists[i].DataBind();


            }           
        }
```

the problem is when i try to get the selected value from checkbox1list1 i got selectedText instead
like this:

```
  protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label7.Text = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        }
```

i got the SelectedText
why "rr" lost its value property?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your 5 CheckBoxLists look like, but I think that you must set their DataValueField and DataTextField properties to get what you want:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList1 runat="server" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" />
```